# What do I need to include that angular bootstrap just simply works

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap, bower

I have included these in my index.html because bower is including them:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
```

Why is the ui-bootstrap.js not included? Because the bower.json from bootstrap and its main property has set "ui-bootstrap-tpls.js" but what about the ui-bootstrap.js?

Even when I include the file outside of the bower:js tags the popover from the datepicker is not visible and I get NO errors in my google chrome.

But when I click on the datepicker button no popover...

UPDATE

Now that I corrected my angularjs modules, now I use just this: `'ui.bootstrap.datepicker'`

I get now these errors in google chrome:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:9000/template/datepicker/datepicker.html
Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: template/datepicker/datepicker.html
```

When I look at the source ui-bootstrap-tpls.js file:

```
.directive( 'datepicker', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: 'template/datepicker/datepicker.html',
    scope: {
      datepickerMode: '=?',
      dateDisabled: '&'
    },
```

Where are these above path template... ? I have them not here. I just installed the angular-bootstrap bower package. Should there not all be included?

**UPDATE2**

I get these angularjs error now:

[image]

See the parent is null and therefore the parent.InsertBefore can not work and throws the exception...

Comment: You have to remove the `ui-bootstrap.js`, otherwise it will override the module (with templates) defined in the `ui-bootstrap-tpls.js`.

Comment: @runTarm Its long ago I had thiese ui-bootstrap.js included. Thats not the cause.

Comment: Then please update your question to prevent a confusion.

Comment: Have you tried include `ui.bootstrap` module after removing the `ui-bootstrap.js`?

Comment: Yes long ago ;-) see my new Update2 above, later I try to do a plunker which repros this error.

Comment: So, you are no longer have the template not found issue right?

Comment: Yes, but the popover for the datepicker is still not shown.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Official Doc](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/wiki/FAQ)

`ui-bootstrap-tpls.js` library contains the directives and the directive templates.

`ui-bootstrap.js` is just the directives and you are expected to supply the directive templates.

Most folks use the predefined directive templates (`ui-bootstrap-tpls.js`). You do not want to include both and that may be why the popover/datepicker is not working. You would essentially have 2 directives working to show/hide the popover/datepicker. Also, do not load the bootstrap.js library as that will cause the same problems.

**UPDATE:**

In regards to the template not found error, the datepicker directive is looking for the template `'template/datepicker/datepicker.html'` in the `$templatecache`.  The `ui-bootstrap-tpls.js` injects the templates into the template cache at the very end of the js file.

In the `ui-bootstrap-tpls.js` file you should see several `$templatecache.put` lines with `'template/datepicker/datepicker.html'` being one of them.

Comment: Not sure, I would start by inspecting the page with developer tools to make sure the correct ui-bootstrap library is being loaded. If you set up a plunk that is reproducing the problem I can help further.

Comment: seems my problem is gone now and I have found the real problem or another problem see my update 2 image!

Comment: damn NO my problem is not gone , I have another error yes but the datepicker popover is not shown when I click the datepicker button. Is there anything I have to activate?

Answer (score 13):

Just in case someone else is having the same issue: I was having problems with the datepicker, and the issue was that I was  loading the templates before the base JS:

From:

```
<script src="/Scripts/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

To:

```
<script src="/Scripts/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this issue also, the answers above helped me a lot!

In my instance I was using a yo-angular build, and installed ui-bootsrap with bower. The problem was multiple references to ui-bootrap and bootstrap conflicting with the tpls.js verison

**Here is my solution:**
Simply put within my index.html

*Remove*

```
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

*Add*

```
<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

## Problem:

This questions comes up as a Google result for

```
Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: templates/datetimepicker.html
```

This may not be a direct answer to your specific problem, but I wanted to leave a note for future users encountering similar problems.

The directive **daleotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker** introduces a breaking change in `v1.0.0`:

> must include datetimepicker.template.js in the page to load the
>   template.
>   ([b520f515](https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/commit/b520f515))

## Solution:

Users of [angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/commit/b520f515) can either roll back to a previous version (such as v0.40), or choose to include templates file that was previously included in the base .js file:

```
// Previously this was the needed file
<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/src/js/datetimepicker.js"></script>
// Users who wish to use the default datetimepicker templates must now also include this file
<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/src/js/datetimepicker.templates.js"></script>
```

Comment: I hit exactly this scenario, thanks for posting as it's not obvious.

Comment: Glad I could help :)